# How to customize Finder sidebar icons

Tags: finder, icon, ui

I'm using Dropbox and replacing some of the standard user folders like *Documents* and *Pictures* with symlinks to locations in my Dropbox. I can easily set the icons of these symlinks to match the icons of the standard *Documents* and *Pictures* folders, but I can't find a way to also change the symlinks' appearance on the Finder sidebar to look like the native *Documents* and *Pictures* folders.

In short, I've placed custom folders in the Finder sidebar; is there a way to change the icons they're given?

I've looked into Candybar, but it seems like that's mostly for changing the appearance of all appearances of the standard icons, whereas I just want to make a plain and ordinary folder look like a standard user folder.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this worked in Snow Leopard, and is broken in Lion (perhaps on purpose). You won't be able to set your own icons for just any folder — [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/) if you'd like to see this fixed. But as you noted, they can be changed for the standard icons, using CandyBar

You can also just edit the image files themselves, at `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`. The icons are named `Sidebar___.icns`.

[image: Icons]